# d3js and Canvas: Setting Alpha lower than 0.01

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, canvas, alpha

This might be a stupid question, or a stupid methodology, I'm open to criticism of those and anything else!

I have a lot of lines that I'm drawing using d3js and Canvas, and I want to really highlight those areas where there are very dense lines. I am currently drawing the lines using the following strokeStyle:

```
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + myFill.r + "," + myFill.g + "," + myFill.b + ",0.01)";
```

But my problem is that this opacity just isn't low enough, I need to go lower, as the slightly less dense areas are too similar to the very dense areas.

I've tried to think outside the box a bit, but I'm struggling to think of what I can do. If I set the alpha of the stroke to anything lower than 0.01 then I get nothing.

Is there something I'm missing, or are there some alternative ideas you can think of?

What I have in my head so far as options, although I'm not certain on the execution yet (basically, not sure what is possible!!!!):

1. Post-process the canvas once finished, looping over pixels and setting the alpha value of the pixel to a different scale, or changing the colour of the pixel depending on the input colour?
2. Some technique using blending of a line to all the other lines?
3. A method of changing the colour of parts of lines based on density once the image is drawn?

Sorry if this is stupid, I've got something that looks pretty good but want to make it look even better by really showing the contrast between very dense and dense for example. Is my strokeStyle even good, maybe that can be improved or changed somehow? I know that it is hard for canvas to draw very low alpha things, but is there a way for me to encourage it to try!!!

Any ideas and comments are very welcome, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, when rendering anything on a canvas, your color is eventually represented by a pixel with four byte (`0` to `255`) values. E.g., the color red:

```
[255, 0, 0, 255]
```

When you define an `rgba()` color, you define your transparency between `0` and `1`. (don't ask me why, all knowledge I have on this topic is purely from playing around with canvas stuff...) My guess is that the minimum alpha difference that will be visible on a canvas would be: `1 / 255 = 0.0039`.

Basically:

```
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0039) -> [0, 0, 0, 0]
rgba(0, 0, 0, 0,0040) -> [0, 0, 0, 1]
```

This means that any alpha difference smaller than 1/255 won't render differently, and any fill with an alpha smaller than 1/255 won't show...

Might have to test this to be absolutely sure though!

*Edit: a test!*

```js
var createCanvas = function(alpha) {
  var cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
  cvs.width = cvs.height = 100;
  var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

  ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0," + alpha + ")";

  for (var i = 0; i < 255; i += 1) {
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, cvs.width, cvs.height)
  }

  document.body.appendChild(cvs);
}

createCanvas(0.0039); // should be transparent and show white
createCanvas(0.0040); // should not be completely white
```

```css
canvas { border: 1px solid red; }
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. So maybe I need to think a bit cleverer here to find a solution which matches what I want, rather than hoping I can get the alpha lower. What I might do is post-process the image to take the RGB values, and if they meet some criteria make them brighter or subtly change the colour or something. Just need to play with the image data to sort that. I'll leave this open in case anyone else offers a creative idea in the meantime, thank you!!!

Comment: I understand my answer didn't really offer a solution; it's more about *why* it happens. I'm curious what other people come up with as well! I'm guessing your best option would be to start varying the `r`, `g`, and `b` values as well...